# I wanted to make an array out of the .dat file

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a .dat file that contains questions and answers written as Object type using

```
ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("QuestionBank.dat"));
```

I have tried to put them into an array split by "-", but it did not work with me.
Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Object line = "";
    String[] qqq = new String[100000];
    try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("QuestionBank.dat"));) {
        output.writeObject("Q: Q1 ...");
        output.writeObject("A ...");
        output.writeObject("B ...");
        output.writeObject("C ...");
        output.writeObject("D ...");
        output.writeObject("-");
        output.writeObject("Q: Q2 ...");
        output.writeObject("A ...");
        output.writeObject("B ...");
        output.writeObject("C ...");
        output.writeObject("D ...");
        output.writeObject("-");
        output.writeObject("Q: Q3 ...");
        output.writeObject("A ...");
        output.writeObject("B ...");
        output.writeObject("C ...");
        output.writeObject("D ...");

    }
    try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("QuestionBank.dat"));) {

        while ((line = input.readObject()) != null) {
            qqq = ((String) line).split("-");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(qqq));

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

you can read file content and split as below

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(PathOfQuestionBankFile), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
String.join("", lines);
qqq = lines.split("-");
```